# why is the margin (total number of sample) important when deciding between hypergeometric and Fisher's exact test

Tags: fishers-exact-test, hypergeometric-distribution

My impression is that both of hypergeometric and Fisher's exact test are similar in calculating the significance of contingency table. The main difference is whether or not you know the margin (if you know the margin, go with hypergeometric test). I have difficult to understand the impact of margin here. Can anyone share some intuitive insights on this？